# Getting proportion of 2 triangles having their angle

Tags: c#, geometry

My problem might not be clear from title but it's quite simple:

```
angleInDegrees = Math.Atan2(vY, vX) * 180 / Math.PI;
```

I need to increase (decrease) vX and vY by double "value" no matter what "angleInDegrees" in that way that if angle is 90 degrees vX will be increased by 100% of "value" and vY by 0 % and if angle is 45 degrees both numbers will be increased by 50% of "value". How can i achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
angleInDegrees = Math.Atan2(vY, vX) * 180 / Math.PI;
vX += value * angleInDegrees / 90.0f;
vY += value * (1 - (angleInDegrees / 90.0f));
```

Comment: works fine as long as angle is between 0 and 90 but I can make the rest myself. It was easier than I thought :D

Answer (score 0):

Literal answer:

```
if (angleInDegrees == 90)
   vX *= 2.0;

if (angleInDegrees == 45)
{
   vX *= 1.5;
   vY *= 1.5;
}
```

P.S. Arguments order of `Atan2` is `(y, x)`

Comment: the assign operator in the if statement has been updated to make it 'equal' operator

Comment: no, i ment to ask about something different. i will edit my question...

Comment: @Vordex Problem is still unclear. Do you want some linear dependence of coefficients for vx, vy  from angle?

Comment: @MBo sadly stack doesn't allow me to send an image at thread so i will do it here http://i.imgur.com/YT39wp5.png i need to get proportion beetwen these 2 triangles that AngleInDegrees creates

Comment: I've inserted this picture in your post. But what is desired proportion?